# How to run two instances of GitBash on Windows 8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, git-bash

so I'm going through the onemonthrails online classes, however I've run into a problem.

Unlike when using a Mac, It's not possible to create a separate 'tab' to continue working whilst the rails server is running or in general. So I've tried just opening another GitBash window like the tutorial suggests, from the programs/apps menu in Windows 8 (whilst the other one is running) but no luck.

Apologies if this is a dumb questions, but am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What happens when you try to open the second one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you have a GitBash tile in the taskbar, click it while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to open additional instances.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to open another app window. Maybe just make sure you're in desktop mode.

Though. If you're going to work on windows for a while, you better start setting up your environment correctly. Honestly, you **don't want to use cmd.exe**.

Instead, use Console2 wrapping a Powershell prompt. Console2 will allow you to use tabs like Unix prompts. There's a guide to setting this up correctly here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx

Also, as you'll now be using Powershell, customize your prompt! For this, I suggest you [install Posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git).

And! To install all this easily and be a windows awesome user, install [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org) and install these programs using it :)